# C# Grab tag data from XML file (includes inner-tags)

Tags: c#, xml, string

**I have the following XML File:**

```
<organizations default="pre-test_organization">
    <organization identifier="data">
        <title>Date</title>
        <item identifier="5BD294BF-0722-45FC-B888-9F31CD076BF9" identifierref="resource">
            <title>Reference</title>
        </item>
    </organization>
</organizations>
<resources>
    <resource identifier="resource" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormtype="sco" href="res/index.html">
        <file href="res/data/apple-touch-icon.png"/>
        <file href="res/data/browsersupport.js"/>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

And i would like to exact data between tag example `<resources>` tag

Im using the following code:

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"D:\extracted\file.xml");
System.Xml.XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
System.Xml.XmlNodeList lst = root.GetElementsByTagName("item");
```

**This returns** (which is correct to the context):

```
Reference
```

**Instead of** (what I really would like to get):

```
<title>Reference</title>
```

Comment: It is better to use LINQ to XML. It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to get `InnerXml`

```
var node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/organizations/organization/item").InnerXml;
```

OR

```
var lst = root.GetElementsByTagName("item")[0].InnerXml;
```